# DataGridView фильтрация данных полученных из источника данных WinForms

Tags: c#, datagridview

Всем привет, возникла такая ситуация. Подключаю `DataGridView` к источнику данных, коим является `DataTable`. Далее мне нужно отбросить строки которые НЕ содержат, например, слово "Ivan" в самом `DataGridView`. Но почему-то все остается на месте. Пробовал через Linq(и методы Linq), ничего у меня не вышло. Как второй вариант я попробовал отфильтровать `DataTable.Rows` тем же способом - результат тот же. Кто знает подскажите пожалуйста. Вот код. В котором я пытаюсь реализовать второй вариант

```
public partial class UserCard : Form
    {
        DataGridView dgv;
        public UserCard(DataGridView dgv)
        {
            this.dgv = dgv;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void UserCard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = dgv.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
            GridUserCard.DataSource = db.DataBase().GetTableForUserCard().Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Where(x=>x["Name"].ToString() == dgv.CurrentCell.Value.ToString()); //Получаю заполненный DataTable и пытаюсь вычленить из него информацию но вылетает исключение
            GridUserCard.AutoSize = true;
            GridUserCard.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
            GridUserCard.Columns[0].Visible = false;            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
GridUserCard.DataSource = db.DataBase().GetTableForUserCard().DefaultView.RowFilter = 
    string.Format("Name = '{0}'", dgv.CurrentCell.Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Можно объяснить путь решения, указать на конкретные ошибки, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы и т. п.